# Instaliing microsoft ADCS using brainpool ECC keys

Tags: certificate-authority, active-directory-adcs

I got a request from a custumer to install ADCS using ECDSA while using a specific ECC curve for the keys (bp384r1). This curve is not listed in the ADCS installation process when creating a new key and choosing the CSP (Only the NIST ECDSA_P384 is there).

I am able to create a leaf certificate by specifing the key algorithm and CSP as 'ECDSA_brainpoolP384r1,Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider'. However this is not displayed in the ADCS installation GUI.

I also tried adding these lines to capolicy.inf before installing the CA but with no success...:
*[NewRequest]*
*KeyAlgorithm=ECDSA_brainpoolP384r1*
*ProviderName="Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider"*

Is there a way to limit the KSP key algortihm to a specific list, Or to change the default ECC curves choosen? Or tell ADCS to use the specific Key Algorithm I want?

Would appriciate any help with this - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft ADCS limits its supported keys to common NIST curves and don't allow to use Brainpool curves. If you manage to supply a certificate with non-supported curve, installer won't accept it. And there is no any workaround I could think of and which would work.

Comment: Is this a limitation of MS CSP or of ADCS?  If I have a HSM that supports brainpool will ADCS accept it?

Comment: It is limitation of ADCS CA, not CSP. This means that it doesn't matter which CSP/KSP you will use, CA just throw an error if sees non-permitted curves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you refer me to a relevant article with the permitted list?

Comment: There is no official documentation on this. Even unofficial, but algorithms you see in installation wizard is the only supported list of algorithms depending on a selected provider.